# How to make the HTML colors of a Bootstrap design edge-to-edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty elementary knowledge of HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap.  So please forgive me if any of the terminology is wrong.

This is the page: http://jowoco.com/stackoverflow/scheduletech.html

On large monitors (resolutions > 1500px) or zoomed out screens (ctrl/cmnd + "-"), you'll see the colors just stop. Ideally the angles would continue, but at the very least it would be nice just to have the colors continued to left and right of the screen as solids (see mock).

I've attached a screenshot of what I think might work as a fix (not sure if it's a div or span), but not sure how to do it in actual practice.

[image: Clean screenshot illustrating the problem]
[image: Annotated proposed solution - not sure how to code this in practice]

Thanks so much in advance for your help and time,
Wojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this...but the easiest by far is to create a linear gradient background for the page, rather than straight white.

This would allow the bar to go from edge to edge even if the main body of the page stops.

Unfortunately, you have not given quite enough information for me to simply hand you the code for it:

1. What is the angle of the blue stripe?
2. Does the geometry of your page change when the browser window is resized?  Specifically, does that blue banner move at all?
3. Which browsers do you need to be able to support?

If you have answers to these questions, feel free to drop them here, and I will update this answer.

If you would rather take a crack at the code yourself, you can generate is at [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).  The resulting code will look something like this:

```
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #ffffff 50%, #91b5b5 50%, #91b5b5 71%, #ffffff 71%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(50%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#91b5b5), color-stop(71%,#91b5b5), color-stop(71%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #ffffff 50%,#91b5b5 50%,#91b5b5 71%,#ffffff 71%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #ffffff 50%,#91b5b5 50%,#91b5b5 71%,#ffffff 71%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #ffffff 50%,#91b5b5 50%,#91b5b5 71%,#ffffff 71%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #ffffff 50%,#91b5b5 50%,#91b5b5 71%,#ffffff 71%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

This code covers all browsers between Firefox, earlier and more recent Chrome, and even down to IE 6-9.

The code, generally, looks far worse than it is... for the bulk of the code, you can directly set the angle at which the blue bar should appear; the exceptions being IE6-9 and earlier versions of Chrome.

Earlier versions of Chrome are probably nearly non-existent, since Chrome generally auto-updates itself... but the earlier Internet Explorer, as always, can be problematic.